# C# httpclient:An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Tags: c#, ubuntu-16.04, dotnet-httpclient, http-proxy, squid

I'm using [YoutubeExplode](https://github.com/Tyrrrz/YoutubeExplode) with proxy to download video from youtube.com.

```
public async Task<ApiResult<List<videoList>>> Search(string videoName)
{
    var res= new ApiResult<List<videoList>>(0,null,null);
    //set proxy
    HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler()
    {
        Proxy = new WebProxy("myvps:port",false),
        UseProxy = true
    };
    using (var client = new HttpClient(handler))
    {
        YoutubeClient youtubeclient = new YoutubeClient(client);
        var list=await youtubeclient.SearchVideosAsync(videoName, 2);
        //convert 
        res.data = list.ToVideoList();
    }
    return res;
}
```

Cause the GFW,I brought a VPS ,installed Squid (a http proxy server) and Configured it simply on Ubuntu16.04 like this

bash:"sudo cp /etc/squid/squid.conf /etc/squid/squid.conf.original"

bash:"vim /etc/squid/squid.conf"

```
http_port 3128
http_access allow all
```

bash:"systemctl restart squid.service"

After that,  When I run the WebApi, I got the wrong message:

```
<ExceptionMessage>
Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
</ExceptionMessage>
```

I viewed squid log

```
1563595921.406      2 117.152.169.17 TAG_NONE/500 0 CONNECT youtube.com:443 - HIER_DIRECT/172.217.5.78 -
1563595921.708      0 117.152.169.17 TAG_NONE/500 0 CONNECT youtube.com:443 - HIER_DIRECT/172.217.5.78 -
1563596804.825      3 117.152.169.17 TAG_NONE/500 0 CONNECT youtube.com:443 - HIER_DIRECT/172.217.14.110 -
1563596805.076      0 117.152.169.17 TAG_NONE/500 0 CONNECT youtube.com:443 - HIER_DIRECT/172.217.14.110
```

I was wondering is there any problem with my configuration file.

So I tried bash:"curl -x vps_ip:port -L https://www.youtube.com",but it seemed worked.

See the log

```
1563599971.588   2930 xxx_xxx_xxx_xxx TCP_TUNNEL/200 385942 CONNECT www.youtube.com:443 - HIER_DIRECT/172.217.14.110 -
```

Any help, please!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if this answer doesn't help.But I was facing similar issues with a WCF asynchronous call .Basically what I was doing was I had made an asynchronous call to the service and I was not awaiting on the result .In the finally block there was a close connection hidden from my sight .So what was happening was since the call was an asynchronous call I probably was closing the call before I had finished executing .

Comment: Probably UR right, So what now I should do is to close the connection manually or any other code advice?

Comment: Are u sure that that is the issue.I am not sure because i dont know much about WebApi.What you can do probably is instead of using SearchVideosAsync you can maybe use the Synchronous version SearchVideos.If you do not face the problem here then we have identified the issue.